# Checking RAID events log or history of a Smart Array P400 in a HP ProLiant DL380 G5 server

Tags: linux, hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

In a rack-mounted [HP ProLiant DL380 G5](http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/home/?sp4ts.oid=1121516) server, running Linux (RHEL - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server - version 5.9, 64-bit): after a shutdown and power on, one of 4 hard disks of a Logical Drive using "RAID 1+0" started "Rebuilding". I was able to check the status using [hpacucli](http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/home/?sp4ts.oid=1121516) ("*HP Array Configuration Utility CLI*") After a few hours, the rebuild was completed successfully (the previously defective hard drive was "physicaldrive 2I:1:2"):

```
$ hpacucli
HP Array Configuration Utility CLI 8.0-14.0
Detecting Controllers...Done.
Type "help" for a list of supported commands.
Type "exit" to close the console.

=> ctrl all show config

Smart Array P400 in Slot 1    (sn: ...)

   array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0 MB)

      logicaldrive 1 (273.4 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)

      physicaldrive 2I:1:1 (port 2I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:2 (port 2I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:3 (port 2I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:4 (port 2I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 146 GB, OK)

...
```

My question is the following: is there a way to see the RAID events history / log of the RAID internal controller (a "Smart Array P400")? I would like to be able to use  "hpacucli" for that, but I can't find any related command in the 
[Hpacucli Utility for Linux - All Commands Guide](http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=341566&docId=emr_na-c03493210&docLocale=en_US)

I may try to use other tools for this, if required (**but not** [HP iLO - "Integrated Lights-Out"](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/servers/ilo/) because I don't have that access), preferably avoiding any reboot. I have checked "/var/log/messages" but I haven't found any seemingly related entries there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hplog -v` command will show you the system event log on servers that have the health management agents installed.